# Matrix/Cross-Tabular/Pivot Reportusing SOQL Grouping in Visualforce

Tags: soql, pageblocktable

I added as many keywords as I could cause finding other questions about this has been a real pain lol. For anyone who doesn't know what I mean, the type of report that has "headers" on the side of each row and each column and the cells are filtered by the header above it and beside it. They are stupid easy to make in a report, yet you seem almsot impossible to display in a dashboard/lightning page outside of hard coding it.

[image: They look like this.]

I know I'm close here. This is my really deep foray into VF but I've learned a TON just doing this project. Anyway, let me know you the code and I'll tell you the errors.

Controller

```
    public class reportResource { 
    class resultMatrix{
        public String WorkGroup {get;set;}
        public String StageName {get;set;}
        public Integer Amount {get;set;}

        public resultMatrix(AggregateResult ar) 
        {
            WorkGroup = (String)ar.get('WorkGroup');
            StageName = (String)ar.get('StageName');
            Amount = (Integer)ar.get('Amount');
        }
    }

    List<AggregateResult> resultList = [SELECT WorkGroup, //**SELECT WorkGroup, Invalid field: 'WorkGroup'** 
                                                StageName, 
                                                FORMAT(SUM(Amount)) 
                                                FROM Opportunity 
                                                GROUP BY WorkGroup, StageName]; 
    List<Opportunity> oppToStore = new List<Opportunity>(); 
    for (AggregateResult ar: resultList) **//Expecting '}' but was: 'for' (it gives me this error two separate times if that. means anything**
    {
      //assign to contacts here. 
      resultMatrix objResultMatrix = new resultMatrix(resultList);
      oppToStore.add(objResultMatrix);
    
    } 
    return oppToStore;
   }
   public List<String> WorkGroup {get; set;}
   public List<String> StageName {get; set;}
   public Map<String, Integer> counts {get; set;}
    private void createCrossTabData() {
    Set<String> WorkGroupset = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> StageNameset = new Set<String>();
    counts = new Map<String, Integer>();
    for (resultMatrix rm : getOpportunityMatrix()) {
        WorkGroupSet.add(rm.WorkGroup);
        StageNameset.add(rm.StageName);
        String key = rm.WorkGroup + '-' + rm.StageName;
        Integer c = counts.get(key);
        if (c == null) {
            c = 0;
        }
        c += rm.Count;
        counts.put(key, c);
    }
    WorkGroups = new List<String>(WorkGroupSet);
    WorkGroups.sort();
    StageNames = new List<String>(StageNameset);
    StageNames.sort();
}
}
```

VF Page

```
    <apex:page controller="reportResource" sideBar="false" standardStyleSheets="false">
      <apex:form id="reportForm">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Matrix Result">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opportunitymatrix)" var="oppToStore"> **//Missing attribute var**
                <apex:column headerValue="Work Group" value="{!oppToStore.WorkGroup}"/>  
                <apex:column headerValue="Stage Name" value="{!oppToStore.StageName}"/>  
                <apex:column headerValue="Amount" value="{!oppToStore.Amount}"/>   
            </apex:pageBlockTable>  
        </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>


      <apex:pageBlock title="Cross-Tab Result">
<table>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <apex:repeat value="{!StageNames}" var="StageName">
        <td><apex:outputText value="{!StageName]}"/></td>
    </apex:repeat>
</tr>
<apex:repeat value="{!WorkGroups}" var="WorkGroup">
<tr>
    <td><apex:outputText value="{!WorkGroup]}"/></td>
    <apex:repeat value="{!StageNames}" var="StageName">
        <td><apex:outputText value="{!counts[WorkGroup + '-' + StageName]}"/></td>
    </apex:repeat>
</tr>
</apex:repeat>
</table>
</apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:page>
```

Spent last night and today just whittling away errors and reading as many examples as I could so I could learn more. I'm down to two errors on each file and I've commented them in the code.

ANY help would really be amazing